# How to get Django/Wagtail to resolve this url

Tags: django, wagtail

I feel like a heel asking this because I'm sure the answer is simple. Nevertheless I've spent hours researching and testing possible solutions and I have been left hairless.

In the project *harmony* I have written my own login page and it resides in an app called *users*.

I have another app called *your_harmony*. To proceed beyond the your_harmony page, users need to login.

**your_harmony.html**

```
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h1>{{ self.sub_title|richtext }}</h1>
        You are logged in as: {{ user.username }} &nbsp
                <a href="/users/logout">Click here to logout</a>
        ...
    {% else %}
         You must login to access this page. <a href="/users/login">Click here to login</a>
    {% endif %}
```

**harmony.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
   ...
    url(r'your-harmony/', include('your_harmony.urls')),
    url(r'^users/', include('users.urls')),
   ...
```

**your_harmony.urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.your_harmony, name='your_harmony')
]
```

The url */users/login* uses *users/views.py* to display the login form

**views.py**

```
RETURN_FROM_LOGIN_URL = 'your-harmony'
RETURN_FROM_LOGIN_URL = 'your_harmony/your_harmony.html'

def login_view(request):
    form_context = {'login_form': LoginForm,}
    url = "users/login.html"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                url = RETURN_FROM_LOGIN_URL
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Your account is not enabled!')
            context = {}
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Your username or password was not recognized!')
            context = form_context
    else:
        context = form_context
    return render(request, url, context)
```

if I return to *'your-harmony'* get the error

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/login/
>
> your-harmony

If I return to *'your_harmony/your_harmony.html'* I get the page but no context.

How should I sort this?

Comment: Template paths and URLs are not the same thing, and redirecting to a new URL is a completely different thing to rendering a template - here you're trying to handle both cases with a call to `render`. I'd suggest working through the Django tutorial, particularly the part on form handling - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @gasman's advice, I have revisited the Django Tutorials. As [Tutorial Part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/) states:

> you should always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good Web development practice in general

So I have changed the code  to include this return and replaced the template path with a URL conf.

**views.py**

```
RETURN_FROM_LOGIN_URL = 'your_harmony'

def login_view(request):
    form_context = {'login_form': LoginForm,}
    url = "users/login.html"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(RETURN_FROM_LOGIN_URL))
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Your account is not enabled!')
            context = {}
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Your username or password was not recognized!')
            context = form_context
    else:
        context = form_context
    return render(request, url, context)
```

Learned a lot and worth the effort